# How do I count the number of messages per day in pycord?

Tags: python, datetime, discord, pycord

So I basicly count all the messages in a channel.
I also want to count the number of messages per day.
I know message.created_at returns a datetime, but how do I count how many times a date is present in this list?

this is my current code:

```
count = 0
async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
    count += 1
    print(message.created_at)
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
count = 0
async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
    count += 1
    dates.append(message.created_at)
print(dates.count(dates[0]))
```

But this just returns "1" (while there are far more different days in the list)

This is my first post on stack overflow, don't be toxic please, feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't counting the number of messages on a certain date, it's counting the message on a certain `datetime.datetime` object, which represents a specific point in time (could be down to a microsecond depending on the API precision).

This is because `message.created_at` returns the *time and date* of the message, what you want is probably `message.created_at.date()` ([see datetime docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)).

If you want to know for each date how many messages there were, you can use a dictionary to count:

```python
messages_per_date = {}  # empty dictionary
async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
    message_date = message.created_at.date()
    # Add the date to the dictionary if necessary
    if message_date not in messages_per_date:
        messages_per_date[message_date] = 0
    # Increment the number of messages on that date
    messages_per_date[message_date] += 1
# Print the number of messages today
print(messages_per_date[datetime.date.today()])
```

You can use [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to make the code significantly shorter:

```python
import collections

# This creates a dictionary in which the default value is zero
messages_per_date = collections.defaultdict(int)

async for message in channel.history(limit=None):
    # Now the values can be incremented without checking the key
    messages_per_date[message.created_at.date()] += 1

print(messages_per_date[datetime.date.today()])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I want to know for each date how many messages were send.

Comment: @Infinibyte I've edited my answer to provide an example :) hope that helps

Comment: Yes exactly what I wanted, thanks!